# Github API: Getting topics of a Github repository

Tags: github, repository, github-api

Github API documentation give instructions to [filter repositories by topics](https://developer.github.com/v3/search/#search-repositories).
Is there a way to use the API to get the topics from a specific repo?

Answer (score 12):

You can do this with the [Github GraphQL API](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/graphql)

Query:

```
{
  repository(owner: "twbs", name: "bootstrap") {
    repositoryTopics(first: 10) {
      edges {
        node {
          topic {
            name
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This will return the first 10 topics and the name for each as shown below.
Response:

```
{
  "data": {
    "repository": {
      "repositoryTopics": {
        "edges": [
          {
            "node": {
              "topic": {
                "name": "css"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "node": {
              "topic": {
                "name": "bootstrap"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "node": {
              "topic": {
                "name": "javascript"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "node": {
              "topic": {
                "name": "html"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Test it out in the [GitHub GraphQL Explorer](https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/)

Answer (score 9):

You can do this easily with Github API (it's currently in "preview mode"):

```
curl -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.mercy-preview+json" https://api.github.com/repos/twbs/bootstrap/topics
{
  "names": [
    "css",
    "bootstrap",
    "javascript",
    "html",
    "jekyll-site",
    "scss",
    "css-framework",
    "sass"
  ]
}
```

You need to include extra header `Accept: application/vnd.github.mercy-preview+json`.

There is one "but", since it's in "preview mode" it's not supported for production use (please read "Note" and "Warning" sections in link below).

See also:

- https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#get-a-repository

Comment: Note that this is not in preview anymore: https://github.blog/changelog/2021-10-14-rest-api-preview-promotions/

Answer (score 8):

I don't know that there is a way to just get the topics for a repository, but if you do a [get for a repository](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#get-a-repository), the repository json object that is returned will have a topics property that is an array of that repositories topics.

**At the top of that page of documentation, you will notice that in order to have the topics returned you will need to add a specific header in your `GET` request: `"Accept":"application/vnd.github.mercy-preview+json"`**

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

I faced similar problem, so I made a node module that only require one line of code to do that which is

```
var github_topics = require('github-topics');
var topics = github_topics.gettopics('url_of_repo');
```

for example

```
var topics = github_topics.gettopics('https://github.com/Aniket965/blog');
```

It will return array of topics of that github repository , link to that node module is [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/github-topics)

Comment: Bringing microdependencies to a whole new level! ;)

Answer (score 2):

I added the fetch with Accept Headers:

```
fetch("https://api.github.com/users/lucksp/repos", 
   {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
    Accept: "application/vnd.github.mercy-preview+json"
   }
})
```